# Show existence of holomorphic function $g$ such that $f(g(z)) = g(z^n)$

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f:\mathbb{C} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ be a holomorphic function, with $f(0)=0$, and $n\ge 0$ the multiplicity of $0$ as a zero of $f$.

Show that there exist a holomorphic function $g:\mathbb{C}\rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ with $g(0)=0$ such that $$f(g(z)) = g(z^n).$$

I know the existence of $g$ such that $f(g(z)) = z^n$, but the above seems out of reach. Any ideas or possible sources for further research?

Comment: This is an important result in complex dynamics as it allows us to understand the nature of a function near a super-attracting fixed point. Thus, you should be able to find a proof in any reasonable text on complex dynamics. It appears as theorem 4.1 on page 33 of [Complex Dynamics](https://www.amazon.com/Complex-Dynamics-Universitext-Lennart-Carleson/dp/0387979425) by Carleson and Gamelin, for example.

Comment: 6.3.2 in "Iterations of rational functions."

Comment: $g$ is only definable in a neighbourhood of zero.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The statement is only true when $n\geq 2$.

Let $G$ be the inverse of $g$. Equation $G\circ f=G^n$ which is equivalent to your
equation is called the Bottcher equation in complex dynamics. Bottcher theorem says that under your condition there exists a solution $G$ analytic in a neighborhood of $0$ with the properties
that $G(0)=0$ and $G'(0)=1$. (Therefore, $G$ is invertible and the inverse is your $g$.) There are many proofs of this. In the most elementary proof, $G$ is constructed as a limit $(f^{*k})^{n^{-k}}$, where $f^{*k}$ is the $k$-th iterate
of $f$. For a complete proof, see any book on holomorphic dynamics.
The best introduction is J. Milnor, Dynamics in one complex variable. Available on arXiv.